# Playing Apple's iMovie dv-file on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, vlc, codecs

I couple of years ago I copied a lot of old family videos using firewire and Apple's iMovie.

I moved now more or less to Ubuntu. I was wondering how I can play this files? I can play them with VLC, but the image has artefacts, seems a codec is missing or something.

Yes, I installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

I'm adding two screenshots, here it's what the video looks like, and the format information

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit and explain what do you mean by "they are not illustrated correct". Also right-click one of them and select Properties. Then open the Audio/Video tab, copy the info and paste it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for editing but next time also give me a nudge like this @CelticWarrior so I can notice the improvements. Now, your problem... First of all please understand VLC always uses its own set of codecs. Installing additional codecs system-wide ("restricted extras") changes nothing for VLC. Have you tried with the default app? It should work but if not it will (hopefully) give you an error message mentioning what codec is missing or other situations. "DV" is a very old format but should be supported, unless the software you used deviates from the "industry standard" for the said format.

Comment: If you still have the MacOS just install Handbrake there and use it to convert to MP4 or MKV.

Comment: In deed I have MacOS running and the dv-file are running there as well, when I am using Quicktime. I can reimport them into iMovie, which takes bloody lot of time (no idea why), then the video is working too. VLC is not (but you are saying VLC is using its own codecs) Yes, if this is the only way then I will convert my video to MKV or so. Is there a good format which is not compressed? I do not want to loose quality.